# Rabbitmq containers throwing error "Bad characters in cookie"

Tags: kubernetes, cookies, rabbitmq, erlang

I am trying to setup a Rabbitmq cluster and when the containers start they are failing with error *[error] CRASH REPORT Process <0.200.0> with 0 neighbours crashed with reason: "Bad characters in cookie" in auth:init_no_setcookie/0 line 313*. This suggests that the erlang cookie value passed in is not valid :

```
kubectl -n demos get pods
NAME                                  READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
mongodb-deployment-6499999-vpcjh   1/1     Running            0          12h
rabbitmq-0                            0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   9          25m
rabbitmq-1                            0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   9          24m
rabbitmq-2                            0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   9          23m
```

And when I query the logs for one of the pods :

```
kubectl -n demos logs -p rabbitmq-0 --previous
```

I get :

```
WARNING: '/var/lib/rabbitmq/.erlang.cookie' was populated from 

'$RABBITMQ_ERLANG_COOKIE', which will no longer happen in 3.9 and later! (https://github.com/docker-library/rabbitmq/pull/424)
Configuring logger redirection
02:04:47.506 [error] Bad characters in cookie
02:04:47.512 [error]
02:04:47.506 [error] Supervisor net_sup had child auth started with auth:start_link() at undefined exit with reason "Bad characters in cookie" in auth:init_no_setcookie/0 line 313 in context start_error

02:04:47.506 [error] CRASH REPORT Process <0.200.0> with 0 neighbours crashed with reason: "Bad characters in cookie" in auth:init_no_setcookie/0 line 313
02:04:47.522 [error] BOOT FAILED
BOOT FAILED
02:04:47.523 [error] ===========
===========
02:04:47.523 [error] Exception during startup:
Exception during startup:
02:04:47.524 [error]

02:04:47.524 [error]     supervisor:children_map/4 line 1250
....
....
....
```

This is how I am generating the cookie in bash :

```
dd if=/dev/urandom bs=30 count=1 | base64
```

And in the secrets manifest I have :

```
metadata:
name: rabbit-secret
  namespace: demos
type: Opaque
data:
  # echo -n "cookie-value" | base64
  RABBITMQ_ERLANG_COOKIE: <encoded_cookie_value_here>
```

And in statefulset I have :

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: rabbitmq
  namespace: demos
spec:
  serviceName: rabbitmq
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: rabbitmq
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: rabbitmq
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: rabbitmq
      initContainers:
      - name: config
        image: busybox
        imagePullPolicy: "IfNotPresent"
        command: ['/bin/sh', '-c', 'cp /tmp/config/rabbitmq.conf /config/rabbitmq.conf && ls -l /config/ && cp /tmp/config/enabled_plugins /etc/rabbitmq/enabled_plugins']
        volumeMounts:
        - name: config
          mountPath: /tmp/config/
          readOnly: false
        - name: config-file
          mountPath: /config/
        - name: plugins-file
          mountPath: /etc/rabbitmq/
      containers:
      - name: rabbitmq
        image: rabbitmq:3.8-management
        imagePullPolicy: "IfNotPresent"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 4369
          name: discovery
        - containerPort: 5672
          name: amqp
        env:
        - name: RABBIT_POD_NAME
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              apiVersion: v1
              fieldPath: metadata.name
        - name: RABBIT_POD_NAMESPACE
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.namespace
        - name: RABBITMQ_NODENAME
          value: rabbit@$(RABBIT_POD_NAME).rabbitmq.$(RABBIT_POD_NAMESPACE).svc.cluster.local
        - name: RABBITMQ_USE_LONGNAME 
          value: "true"
        - name: RABBITMQ_CONFIG_FILE
          value: "/config/rabbitmq"
        - name: RABBITMQ_ERLANG_COOKIE
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: rabbit-secret
              key: RABBITMQ_ERLANG_COOKIE
        - name: K8S_HOSTNAME_SUFFIX
          value: .rabbitmq.$(RABBIT_POD_NAMESPACE).svc.cluster.local
        volumeMounts:
        - name: data
          mountPath: /var/lib/rabbitmq
          readOnly: false
        - name: config-file
          mountPath: /config/
        - name: plugins-file
          mountPath: /etc/rabbitmq/
      volumes:
      - name: config-file
        emptyDir: {}
      - name: plugins-file
        emptyDir: {}
      - name: config
        configMap:
          name: rabbitmq-config
          defaultMode: 0755
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: data
    spec:
      accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
      storageClassName: "cinder-csi"
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 50Mi
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: rabbitmq
  namespace: labs
spec:
  clusterIP: None
  ports:
  - port: 4369
    targetPort: 4369
    name: discovery
  - port: 5672
    targetPort: 5672
    name: amqp
  selector:
    app: rabbitmq
```

What am I missing ?

Is there a recommended way of generating the cookie or something else to do with the K8s cluster itself.

I have followed the example given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59444617/rabbitmq-how-to-create-rabbitmq-erlang-cookie) with the only difference being that I am generating my cookie on my local machine and not the k8s host.

Answer (score 0):

[duplicate question?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59444617/rabbitmq-how-to-create-rabbitmq-erlang-cookie?noredirect=1&lq=1)

This requires you to create the Secret. Just to bring this up, you can run a one-off imperative command to create a random Secret:

```
kubectl create secret generic rabbitmq \
  --from-literal=erlangCookie=$(dd if=/dev/urandom bs=30 count=1 | base64)
```

The error is from the rabbitmq's source code file `docker-entrypoint.sh`

```
if [ "${RABBITMQ_ERLANG_COOKIE:-}" ]; then
    cookieFile='/var/lib/rabbitmq/.erlang.cookie'
    if [ -e "$cookieFile" ]; then
        if [ "$(cat "$cookieFile" 2>/dev/null)" != "$RABBITMQ_ERLANG_COOKIE" ]; then
            echo >&2
            echo >&2 "warning: $cookieFile contents do not match RABBITMQ_ERLANG_COOKIE"
            echo >&2
        fi
    else
        echo "$RABBITMQ_ERLANG_COOKIE" > "$cookieFile"
    fi
    chmod 600 "$cookieFile"
fi
```

Therefore you can delete `'/var/lib/rabbitmq/.erlang.cookie'` file, the code will copy the content from environment variable `$RABBITMQ_ERLANG_COOKIE` to create this file.

If you are working for the production system, you should be very careful and test it in your local system firstly and gain experience.

This source code will be execuated only the rabbitmq restart, and won't run again after it is execuated.
And you can find the actual rabbitmq's cookie data from the erlang's console by `erlang:get_cookie() -> Cookie | nocookie`.

Comment: I did the fix but now getting error as : warning: /var/lib/rabbitmq/.erlang.cookie contents do not match RABBITMQ_ERLANG_COOKIE

WARNING: '/var/lib/rabbitmq/.erlang.cookie' was populated from '$RABBITMQ_ERLANG_COOKIE', which will no longer happen in 3.9 and later! (https://github.com/docker-library/rabbitmq/pull/424)
Configuring logger redirection
06:39:57.022 [error]

06:39:57.019 [error] Bad characters in cookie
06:39:57.019 [error] Supervisor net_sup had child auth started with auth:start_link() at undefined exit with reason "Bad characters in cookie" in auth:init_no_setcookie/0

Comment: I have searched the rabbitmq source code for the keyword $RABBITMQ_ERLANG_COOKIE for the warning message, and updated the solution in the above message.

Comment: To re-confirm if I got it you are saying once I delete  /var/lib/rabbitmq/.erlang.cookie the code should then detect the change and run accordingly? Do I delete /var/lib/rabbitmq/.erlang.cookie in all pods or this is present in only 1 pod. I assume its in all the pods .    I have tried to "kubectl exec -it -n demos rabbitmq-0 -- sh " but I am getting an error "Defaulted container "rabbitmq" out of: rabbitmq, config (init)
error: unable to upgrade connection: container not found ("rabbitmq")" . It appears as if I cant exec into the pods/containers.

Comment: Updated the above message again.

Comment: erlang console ? Can I access it ordinarily because I only have kubectl access. I dont have access to the k8s host. Unless you mean the console is available automatically (to the host) via the rabbitmq containers that are running on the host itself. Sorry but I am a bit lost there how to. I have tried to run it as is on the command line and Im getting erlang:get_cookie() -> Cookie | nocookie
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `-'

Comment: I think I cant also exec into the pods since the containers are crashing -- just realized now

Comment: You have to delete this file in all instance. Once it deleted, the rabbitmq should be restarted again. You should tested it in one instance firstly. If you don't know how to run rabbitmq by console mode, forget it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245071/discussion-between-golide-and-chen-yu).